# Как добавить псевдоэлемент перед маркером списка?

Tags: html, css

Например, добавить "1.2", чтобы в итоге список был:
`1.2.1 1.2.2 1.2.3` и т.д.

Comment: Никак, к псевдо-элементу нельзя добавить ещё один псевдо-элемент. (`::marker` - это псевдо-элемент)

Comment: Нужен просто нумерованный многоуровневый список?

Answer (score 7):

Такая разметка по умолчанию создаст для каждого вложенного списка новую нумерацию, начинающуюся с единицы. Чтобы сделать вложенную нумерацию, нужно использовать следующие свойства:

`counter-reset` сбрасывает один или несколько счётчиков, задавая значение для сброса;

`counter-increment` задаёт значение приращения счётчика, т.е. с каким шагом будет нумероваться каждый последующий пункт;

`content` — генерируемое содержимое, в данном случае отвечает за вывод номера перед каждым пунктом списка.

```css
ol {
  /* убираем стандартную нумерацию */
  list-style: none;
  /* Идентифицируем счетчик и даем ему имя li. Значение счетчика не указано - по умолчанию оно равно 0 */
  counter-reset: li;
}

li:before {
  /* Определяем элемент, который будет нумероваться — li. Псевдоэлемент before указывает, что содержимое, вставляемое при помощи свойства content, будет располагаться перед пунктами списка. Здесь же устанавливается значение приращения счетчика (по умолчанию равно 1). */
  counter-increment: li;
  /* С помощью свойства content выводится номер пункта списка. counters() означает, что генерируемый текст представляет собой значения всех счетчиков с таким именем. Точка в кавычках добавляет разделяющую точку между цифрами, а точка с пробелом добавляется перед содержимым каждого пункта списка */
  content: counters(li, ".") ". ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>пункт
    <ol>
      <li>подпункт
      </li>
      <li>подпункт
        <ol>
          <li>подпункт</li>
          <li>подпункт</li>
          <li>подпункт</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>подпункт</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>пункт
    <ol>
      <li>подпункт</li>
      <li>подпункт</li>
      <li>подпункт
        <ol>
          <li>подпункт</li>
          <li>подпункт</li>
          <li>подпункт</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>подпункт</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>пункт</li>
  <li>пункт</li>
</ol>
```

Подробнее про CSS счетчики и функцию `counters()` на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters)

Comment: Ничего себе... Оказывается я CSS не знаю...

Comment: А почему это работает? Вы же написали псевдокласс, а не элемент (`li:before`).

Comment: @ΝNL993 https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters

Comment: я уже ознакомился со статьёй в MDN, это не даёт никакого объяснения почему используя псевдокласс `:before` вы смогли воссоздать работу псевдоэлемента `::before`.

Comment: @ΝNL993, нет такого псевдокласса, как `:before`. Есть только псевдоэлемент `::before`. С одним двоеточием *before* используется только для совместимости со старыми браузерами.

Comment: @UModeL Так я это и мел ввиду (В смысле то что нет такого псевдокласса). Вопрос, а где можно узнать какие псевдоэлементы поддерживают такое написание? (Или же они все его поддерживают?)

Comment: @ΝNL993, насколько я знаю, таких элементов всего четыре: `:before`, `:after`, `:first-letter` и `:first-line`. Хотя документация уверяет, что двойной синтаксис поддерживается всеми современными браузерами и для всех псевдоэлементов, лучше не стоит экспериментировать. Подробнее в [примечании](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements#%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81).

Answer (score 1):

Другое дело если мы прибегним к помощи JavaScript-а...

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((e, i) => {
  e.dataset.n = i+1
})
```

```css
li::marker {
  content: '1.2.'attr(data-n)' ';
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
  <li>123</li>
</ol>
```

К каждому `li` просто добавляем атрибут `data-n` со значением его индекса, а потом в CSS у маркера меняем контент на `1.2.(текущий индекс)` .